# How to create an Ethereum mining pool.

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, ethereumj, mining-pools

How would one begin to create an Ethereum mining pool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Full instructions and software is available at https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool